# Porque no funciona la transicion en este ejemplo?

Tags: html5, css3

Porque no funciona la transicion de rotar? que estoy haciendo mal?

```css
#circulo
{
 position: relative;
 width: 15%;
 padding-bottom: 15%;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
 border-radius: 50%;
}
#subcirculo1
{
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, 
    rgba(2,113,76,1.00) 0);
 border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
 z-index: 1;
 
 
}
#subcirculo2
{
 position: absolute;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 0);
 border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
 z-index: 2;
    transition: all 5s ease; 
}
```

```html
<div id="circulo">
    <div id="subcirculo1">
    </div>
    <div id="subcirculo2">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente omitiste el `@keyframes`;

> Ahora bien no se si este es el efecto deseado, comentalo y te puedo
>   ayudar mas aun.

quedaría de la siguiente manera(observa al final se muestra el nuevo contenido):

```
#circulo
{
    position: relative;
    width: 15%;
    padding-bottom: 15%;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00);
    border-radius: 50%;
  animation:circulo_giratorio 1s ease infinite;
}
#subcirculo1
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, 
    rgba(2,113,76,1.00) 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    z-index: 1;


}
#subcirculo2
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, white 0);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    z-index: 2;
    transition: all 5s ease; 
}
 @keyframes circulo_giratorio {
 0% {
transform: rotate(360deg);
}
 100% {
transform: rotate(0deg);
}
}
```